# What is exactly ortho effect in Reimmer-Timmer reaction?

Tags: aromatic-compounds

In the **Reimmer-Timmer** reaction cho group is added to only at **ortho position** not at para position , I got the answer for this as **ortho effect**. So what is exactly ortho effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the coordination step is responsible for the ortho selectivity. The phenoxide anion has a large negative charge on the oxygen atom, so the electron-poor carbene will tend to go there and the conjugated attack will result in the ortho product.